# Sql foreign key error - can't update  a child row error

Tags: sql, error-handling

I have 6 tables in all, but I'm trying to add a foreign key to one table (user) to reference party table

I'm getting an error that I can't update  a child row error 1452

I'm fairly new to sql. can anyone help is my null value wrong?

```
grant all on election.* to 'user_id'@'localhost';
set password for 'user_id'@'localhost' =password('userpassword');

CREATE TABLE user
(
    const_id INT (11) ,
    username VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL, 
    passwd VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    const VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (const_id)
);

ALTER TABLE user ADD Foreign Key (passwd) references party (party_id);
```

party table......

```
CREATE TABLE party
( 
    party_id VARCHAR (25) ,
    member VARCHAR (20),
    leader VARCHAR (20),
    address VARCHAR (25),
    PRIMARY KEY(party_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

first create party table then create user.  in mssql you cannot set tablename to 'user'.
if party table not exist when you do **references party (party_id);** the table party not exist. its the error.